# How to configure Resharper to work together with source generators in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: resharper, sourcegenerators

*(Note: this question is not logging related, and also not related with Microsoft's logging source generator. Resharper behaves exactly this way with any other source generator, I just using `LoggerMessageAttribute` as example.)*

I have the following method which is using `LoggerMessageAttribute` to trigger Microsoft logging source generator:

```
public partial class Logger
{
    [LoggerMessage(Level = LogLevel.Information, Message = "Generating {ForecastCount} forecasts")]
    public static partial void GeneratingForecasts(ILogger logger, int forecastCount);
}
```

My application compiles and runs properly, my issue is related to the developer experience.
When I `ctrl+click` on `GeneratingForecasts` method if Resharper is active it opens a new text editor tab, with empty content, even after a successful build. The title on the tab is `logging.g.cs`, which seems to be correct, but obviously Resharper is looking the generated file in the wrong place, or something else is going wrong.

**If I turn off Resharper**, *and do nothing else*, then Visual Studio's own `ctrl+click` on `GeneratingForecasts` method navigates correctly to the generated source.

What am I missing?

Visual Studio version: 17.8.0
Resharper version: 232.0.20231101.132807 built on **2023-11-01**

Comment: Seems like R# links you to the compiler-generated file rather than the actual partial code which feels like a bug to me. Have you tried using `F12` for navigation instead `ctrl+click`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing the latest ReSharper - [2023.3.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/#section=offline-installer), this should help. The issue appears to be fixed as it is not reproducible in this version.